# XEX vs EME mode of operation

Tags: encryption, authenticated-encryption

Two of the [CAESAR finalists](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/caesar-submissions.html) use XEX and EME mode of operations (COLM uses EME, OCB uses XEX).

I did literature to summarize the main advantages / disadvantages but I could not find much. My question is the following:
What are the main advantages/ limitations of both?

Comment: Please make a separate question to compare ACORN against ChaCha-Poly. I have also removed the off-topic implementation request (which a short search should answer anyways).

Comment: XEX and EME are _completely_ different. The former is a tweakable narrow block cipher, the latter is a wide block cipher. Put simply, XEX is faster but more malleable. EME is twice as slow but not very malleable. Note that neither are authenticated modes of encryption.